# MySQL: Merge two different tables without JOIN or UNION

Tags: mysql, join, merge, union

I need to merge two tables:

- Both have a primary key-column date, but with different values (different time intervals).
- Both have different (unknown) columns: I don't know the names of the columns (same column-name may occur in both tables), I don't know how many columns, but all of the same type.

An example:

```
table1
date       | colA | colB | colC
2011-02-02 | 1.09 | 1.03 | 1.04

table2
date       | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
2011-02-03 | 1.03 | 1.02 | 1.07 | 1.03
```

the result of the query should look like this:

```
tableResult
date       | colA | colB | colC | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
2011-02-02 | 1.09 | 1.03 | 1.04 | null | null | null | null
2011-02-03 | null | null | null | 1.03 | 1.02 | 1.07 | 1.03
```

This will not work:

- `INNER JOIN` because it will only return the intersection between `table1` and `table2`,
- `OUTER JOIN` returns intersection + values only from left table (or right table if right join is used)
- `UNION` because the count of columns may differ.

Any Ideas?

Christoph

Comment: I have a solution but in contains the primary keys redundant. Would it be ok for you?

Comment: What to do if fields 'colA' have different values for the same date? One of the tables should be main.

Comment: the column names are adresses of sensors in a simple sensor-network. So same column name in both tables means same sensor. The similar value in both entries would simply be the same value. 
`DISTINCT` could help on this issue, if I'm not wrong. On the other hand, the date-intervals differ on both tables in a way they should never collide (even values vs. odd values)

Comment: @Christoph, Any better solution you found Please suggest me...i had same case...

Comment: @samirprogrammer: nope, no better solution was found by myself, see below the given answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a temp table with the union of just the date column, and then use the temp table to left outer join with the other 2.

Example:

```
DROP TABLE temptbl IF EXISTS;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptbl (myDate DATETIME PRIMARY KEY)
    AS (SELECT MyDate FROM table1)
    UNION (SELECT MyDate FROM table2)
    ORDER BY MyDate;
SELECT * FROM temptbl
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 USING (MyDate)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 USING (MyDate);
```

Comment: yes, thats right. 

Here's an example for the code above: 
`DROP TABLE temptbl IF EXISTS;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptbl (myDate DATETIME PRIMARY KEY) AS (SELECT MyDate FROM table1) UNION (SELECT MyDate FROM table2)
ORDER BY MyDate; 
SELECT * FROM temptbl LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 USING (MyDate) LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 USING (MyDate);`

Answer (score 0):

```
select coalesce(t2.data,'')+coalesce(t1.data,'') as data,
    t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3 ,t2.col4 ,t1.cola ,t1.colb, t1.colc
from table2 as t2
full outer join 
table1 t1
on t2.data = 2011-02-03
or t1.data = 2011-02-02
```